# How to get the directors using IMBdPY as a list?

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to get names of directors as a list.    Thanks in advance

```
import imdb

ia = imdb.IMDb()
mInfo = ia.search_movie('Avengers: Infinity War')
mID = mInfo[0].movieID
movie = ia.get_movie(mID)
for i in movie['director']:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
directorList = list()
for i in movie['director']:
    directorList.append(str(i))

print(directorList)
```

Output:

```
['Anthony Russo', 'Joe Russo']
```